# Cassandra DB, cluster not able to form

Tags: cassandra

I have two nodes installed Cassandra and trying to make cluster between two.

IP1 - 10.0.0.2

IP2 - 10.0.0.3

Getting below error while starting cassandra in cluster mode.

```
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-3] 2022-08-08 15:15:36,172 NoSpamLogger.java:92 - /10.0.0.3:7000->/10.0.0.2:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-[no-channel] failed to connect
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: No route to host: /10.0.0.2:7000
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: No route to host
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:124)
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:673)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:530)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
ERROR [main] 2022-08-08 15:15:37,034 CassandraDaemon.java:911 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any peers
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1844)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:650)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:936)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:786)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:731)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:420)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:765)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:889)
```

In Cassandra yaml file, I have added as,

Ip1 yaml file,

listen_address: 10.0.0.2

rpc_address: 10.0.0.2

seeds: "10.0.0.3:7000"

Ip2 yamle file,

listen_address: 10.0.0.3

rpc_address: 10.0.0.3

seeds: "10.0.0.3:7000"

Below are the ports enabled.

8888, 7000, 7001, 7199, 9042, 9142, 9160

Answer (score 0):

You need to check few things.

1.Please check with ping if both servers/nodes are reachable from each other.

2.Cassandra communicate/gossip on port 7000, please check if the port is allowd in OS firewall. If you are using SSL for inter-done communication the port would be 7001

3. Make sure 9042 and 9160 is enabled for client and thrift communication.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Able to ping to the other machine but was not ablet to do telnet to it. Cluster able to form once we resolve telnet issue. Now able to form cluster.

Comment: So it was firewall which was not allowing the port. Correct?